# MVC routing with "optional" routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm a bit baffled by how MVC is figuring out my routing details. Let me see if I can explain this right.

So ... given that I have the default route ...

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "CMS", action = "GetPage", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

And my app is a content management system so I want to create nice urls from the site structure so i'll map a wildcard url that lets me determine if i need to render a 404 based on what's in my database ...

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CMS",
    "{*path}", 
    new { controller = "CMS", action = "GetPage", path = string.Empty } 
);
```

Herein lies the problem.

MVC will basically match everything to the default route because technically no params are required assuming "GetPage" on the "CMS" controller requires no params, which is not what i want.

What i'm trying to say to it is something like "given 2 or 3 url parts, look for a controller and action match with an optional id parameter but for all other urls including ones that you can't match to this route fall down in to the CMS route".

The only "easy" way I found to do this is to change the first route to something like this ...

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "Get/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "CMS", action = "GetPage", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then any url that starts "Get/" will match that route and all other routes automatically fall down in to the second route, but that doesn't sit right somewhere in my head and I can't figure out quite why yet (i think it's because it doesn't really solve the problem it simply moves it).

My problem is that I don't really want a route that says "given no values match this route anyway" so I changed it to this ...

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
);
```

Now for some odd reason literally every request is hitting the catch all (not quite what i want but close).

So any ideas guys?

EDIT:

I came a touch closer with this ...

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", 
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
        new { id = UrlParameter.Optional}
    );
```

... but that now matches all urls with 2 parts "foo/bar" rather than dropping through like it should to the other route because there is no "foo" controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have a solution, it works for me because 99% of requests need to map to the CMS route but in your case it may not if you have a lot of controllers you need to map to.

I was hoping to find an ideal solution for all but this is merely an ideal in my scenario ...

So assuming you have (like me) only a cms controller and a an accounts controller you can do this:

```
    routes.MapRoute("Account", "Account/{action}", new { controller = "Account" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{*path}", 
        new { controller = "CMS", action = "GetPage", path = string.Empty } 
    );
```

That way only urls starting with "Account" get caught by the first rule, and everything else falls through to the default route and gets handled by the cms controller.

I plan to simply add more routes as I add more controllers. It's not an ideal solution because it could mean i end up with a lot of route mappings in the long term but its a good enough solution to meet my needs.

Hope it helps someone else out there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand your problem fully but why not have this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "CMS",
   "CMS/{action}/{path}", 
   new { action = "GetPage", path = string.Empty } 
);
```

and add it into the route collection before your default path...

Comment: i want to say "here's the format of a url that might map to a controller, but should you find a controller does not exist with part 1 of the url as its name fall through to default route and map to getpage on cms controller"

Comment: my answer to this question does solve the problem but its not an ideal because i would have to create a rule for every controller for urls to match them. I was hoping to use something more global, a single rule that could do the same thing, this solution is basically the same as mine, it doesn't catch all controllers that exist and fall through where they dont.